# Heroku mLab add-on vs mLab

Tags: node.js, heroku, mlab

I am considering whether to use Heroku mLab add-on or mLab separately - only from performance perspective.

I was somehow thinking that in case I use add-on on Heroku, things should work faster as I imagined database should be on the same infrastructure.

Anyone has any experience on this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku infrastructure is run on AWS. The mLab Heroku Add-on is available in the United States and Europe Heroku regions (https://elements.heroku.com/addons/mongolab). These correspond to AWS us-east-1 or eu-west-1.

So say your Heroku application is hosted in the United States or Europe region. An mLab Add-on would be co-located with your application. A standalone mLab deployment would also be co-located with your application if you chose to deploy it into AWS us-east-1 or eu-west-1 (whichever one your application is using). There should be no difference in latency between the two options.

If you are using a Heroku Private Space which isn't in the US or EU region, then the mLab Add-on is not available. In that case, you may wish to use a separate mLab deployment. But note that free Sandbox Plans are only available in us-east-1 or eu-west-1. You can see more about availability of the mLab Add-on here: https://elements.heroku.com/addons/mongolab

So in the end of the day, if you are hosting your application in the US or EU regions, it won't impact performance. It comes down to what you personally find more convenient.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I also checked with mLab support and they gave me the same answer in the meantime :).